# prevent jquery datepicker from redirecting on date click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have initialized datepicker on input type element.

On clicking any dates, it automatically redirects to base-url of the project.

```
localhost/my-project/#
```

I have used the plug-in other pages too but it worked fine.

Here's the input element. This element gets hidden initially, and later displayed via javascript.

```
<input class="editInput date form-control input-sm" type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $menu['date']; ?>" style="display: none;">
```

jquery DatePicker initialization:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('input[name="date"]').datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
     });
</script>
```

Could it because the element is hidden initially in DOM?

How do I fix it?

Comment: what plugin are you using?

Comment: @seethrough jquery-datepicker

Comment: Could it be that you maybe reused a class or name, that you used to redirect to somewhere else? Because in the code provided I don't see anything that would lead to this problem. Also try to not use css in elements. Use an external css file so if you later want to change your css you don't have to adjust in 100 different places, just a tip.

Comment: It's because it is not inside <form> </form> element. Just realized it.

Answer (score 0):

Find The class 'ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all' in jquery-Ui
then you can see the anchor tag now you just need to add href='#'